# HTML/JS Canvas draw line between objects

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I need help with my project. I making ERD Diagram generator in HTML5, JS and CSS3. I miss only one function in my project, that is linking two objects(rectangles). I tried to make this function, but it only works straightforwardly but i want lines with 90 degrees angle.
For better exaplain, here is what i have now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpfKb.png
And this is what i want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCNKX.png
So here is function what want and i cant figure out:
This function must take 2 objects. Objects have Position X and Y, width and height. And function calculate best sides to link these two objects and 90 degrees angle in this objetcs. 
So for example, it return: 
(Start Point)Point1: 123,566 
(Point where line wrap) Point2: 223,766
(Point where line wrap) Point3: 153,266
(End Point)Point4: 33,234
Any ideas? I only want suggestion of algorithm. Thanks guys :).

Comment: what is "Point where line wrap" I didn't get it's purpose, and how come your function is returning three value-pairs?

Comment: Its point where is center of line, where wraps. If you look at second image, line have three points. For better example. In first picture i have only two points, and that makes one line. But i want to make two lines whose made from three points.

Comment: the image shows 4 points, two points on the line segment and the two end points. which three points are you considering?

Comment: Yeah, im idiot. I mean yes, its four points. Sorry.

Comment: I am still not very clear with return values concept, but I guess Daew answered your query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Figure out which object has smaller `left` and which smaller `top` value (if this is how you position them)
2. Figure out height and width of both objects.
3. Figure out start and end points:

   - X of start point is at `left + width` of left object
   - Y of start point is at `top + height/2` of left object
   - X of end point is at `left` of right object
   - Y of end point is at `top + height/2` of right object
4. "Point where line wraps" is at Y of start point and at X that is between X of start and X of end point. The second point where line wraps is at Y of end point and has same X.
5. Connect the 3 points the same way you connected objects before.

Sorry for not posting code. If you post code of your example I can add it to answer.